# Recursively computing all possible permutations of a string Java

Tags: java, string, recursion, permutation

I am trying to compute all possible permutations of a given string using recursion in Java. However, I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Here's my algorithm:

```java
public static ArrayList<String> computeAllPossiblePermutations(String str) {
    ArrayList<String> perms = new ArrayList<>();
    //base case
    if (str.length() == 1)
        perms.add(str);
    else {
        //loop over the string
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            //make a subset of the string excluding the first char
            String sub = str.substring(i + 1, str.length());
            //compute permutations of the subset
            ArrayList<String> subPerms = computeAllPossiblePermutations(sub);
            //add the first char that we excluded at the start of each permutations
            for (String s : subPerms) {
                s = str.charAt(i) + s;
                perms.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    return perms;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. The following line: `String sub = str.substring(i+1, str.length());` ignores the first character
2. The same line also treats anything after index `i` as a "block" of substring that is left unchanged, while in order to generate permutation we should insert the current (first) character in between any two characters of the rest of the string - and do that for each permutation
3. The line `s = str.charAt(i) + s;` repeats the same mistake in #2

Here's a suggested fix:

---

```
public static ArrayList<String> computeAllPossiblePermutations(String str) {
    ArrayList<String> perms = new ArrayList<>();
    if (str.length() == 1) {
        perms.add(str);
    } else {
        String chr = str.substring(0,1);
        String rest = str.substring(1);
        ArrayList<String> subPerms = computeAllPossiblePermutations(rest);
        for (String s : subPerms) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= s.length(); j++) {
                String newPerm = s.substring(0,j) + chr + s.substring(j);
                perms.add(newPerm);
            }
        }
    }
    return perms;
}
```